# Tell me how you are? Tell me how are you?

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clauses, interrogatives

> 1. Tell me how you are?
> 2. Tell me how are you?

Which one is correct?

I am confused. 
Which is the best and most correct sentence?

Answer (score 2):

"Tell me how you are." (no question mark) is the most grammatically correct written English.

However, in informal spoken English, you might hear, "Tell me...how are you?"

Answer (score 0):

The first is correct (with no question mark) because, when you use a helping verb (in this case, tell) the second verb goes to the end, so it goes from "tell me" plus "how are you?" to "tell me how you are." You may hear "tell me, how are you?" but that is different than "tell me how are you?" because of the comma, which denotes that there are two separate clauses. They may sound the same spoken, but are not the same written, and only the one with the comma (other punctuation may also be used instead of a comma) is correct.